# how to install gzip Model in nginx

Tags: nginx, gzip

i want to install gzip on linux centos my web server is nginx How can I install
I receive the following error after reload Nginx

```
[root@server ~]# /etc/init.d/nginx reload
nginx: [emerg] "gzip" directive is not allowed here in /etc/nginx/nginx.conf:131
nginx: configuration file /etc/nginx/nginx.conf test failed
```

Thank you

Comment: I think the issue isn't that it isn't installed, I think you used it in the wrong context, because nginx identified the 'gzip' directive, please share your config so we could help you.

Answer (score 1):

hope this might help: [Enable gzip compression](https://rtcamp.com/tutorials/nginx/enable-gzip/)